# How do I hide the Timeline in the 'Task List' data view web part using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

Using SharePoint Designer 2013 I've created a Data View web part that links to a Task List on my SharePoint 2013 site - and it all works as I'd expect.

The only thing I can't seem to do is to remove the timeline...

When I look at the Web Part properties within SharePoint Designer there is no option for the timeline so I can't hide it from there and I can't seem to find any other way to hide it via the code.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. I'd created the page as a 'non-webpart' page. When I created a webpart page I was able to add the webpart and then amend it according.

Answer (score 8):

1. Navigate to the Task List and (in the ribbon) click on 'List' -> 'Modify View'.
2. In the view settings page that opens up, scroll down near the bottom of the page and expand the 'Style' section.
3. On the right, UNDER the View Style selection box that appears, there is a check box labeled 'Show timeline above the view'. Un-check this check box then click the 'OK' button.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the advanced edit mode in the designer you can change the WebPart XML:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ShowTimelineIfAvailable="False">
```

The **ShowTimelineIfAvailable** Attribute will hide the timeline when you set it to false

Comment: This works for the first time but then somehow Sharepoint Designer removes this attribute and the timeline re-appears.

So I really wonder what exactly does the "Show timeline" checkbox change and where.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it can be done with code.  You can edit the properties of the web part in the browser, and deselect the Timeline option there, but the option is not available in the properties window in Designer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if I could edit the web parts on the page I am creating this may be a solution but I'm not able to as I don't get the option.

Maybe I need to go back to the drawing board and look at how I've created the page in the first place!

Comment: I tried comparing the markup when the timeline is disabled, and when it's enabled, but I could not find any differences.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the Task List and (in the ribbon) click on 'List' -> 'Modify View'. In the view settings page that opens up, scroll down near the bottom of the page and expand the 'Style' section. On the right, UNDER the View Style selection box that appears, there is a check box labeled 'Show timeline above the view'. Uncheck this check box then click the 'OK' button.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the answer a little to help the OP more? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to remove timeline through code.

### Code first:

```
var spView = myList.Views.Cast<SPView>().FirstOrDefault(v => v.Title == "ViewToManipulate");

if (spView != null)
{
    // remove timeline. yep. 
    spView.ViewData = spView.ViewData.Replace(@"<FieldRef Name=""DueDate"" Type=""TimelineDueDate"" />",string.Empty);
    spView.Update();
}
```

### Explain the magic

A 'clean' view will have the following `ViewData`

```
<ViewData>
    <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete" />
    <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate" />
</ViewData>
```

Modified view will have the following `ViewData`

```
<ViewData>
    <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete" />
</ViewData>
```

### How I found it:

I've used **ErwinHernandez** answer, and then compared the `ViewData` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the timeline in SharePoint 2013/2016 task lists by following below steps-

1. Go to the Task List, Click on List Tab and then click on "Modify
   View" button from the ribbon.
2. In the Edit view page, scroll down and expand the 'Style' section.
3. Under the Style selection, Uncheck the checkbox 'Show timeline above the view
4. click on 'OK' button to save changes.